# jQuery slideUp div if already slided down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidedown, slideup

I have a simple question about jquery slideDown, SlideUp. I'm using slideDown to slide a div on click, like

```
$("#box").slideDown("slow");
```

How can I do it so that if the #box is already slided down, it should slide up by clicking again? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use [.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) instead

`$("#box").slideToggle("slow");`